# How do you get a list of files in a directory with javascript in html on server side?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an array of file names from a server side folder in javascript, how do you do this or are you not able to do this at all? I'm looking for something like this:

```
var file_names = get_files_by_dir(path)
```

Comment: You can use `node` to do this. The browser can not do it itself. It needs to request to a server such as `node`, `php`, `python`, etc.

Comment: Do you mean from the browser, client side?

Comment: You mean you want to see a list of server-side files from the browser? This is not a feature you get automatically, as it could be a security vulnerability. You need to create an API to retrieve the files from the server. In other words, write server-side code (nodejs, PHP, or whatever your server is written in) to listen for requests for a list of files, and then you need to call that API as an ajax request from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using node's asynchronous `readdir()` method ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback))

```
function getFiles(folder){
  const testFolder = folder;
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
      console.log(file);
    });
  });
}
```